# Connect to Office365 of Exchange Online with cfexchange tag

Tags: coldfusion, http-status-code-302

Has anyone had success using `<cfexchange>` to connect to a cloud based exchange service, in particular Office365?

We are migrating our users to Office365 for Exchange and I'm getting the following error :

```
Unable to connect to the Exchange server using HTTP/HTTPS protocol.
HTTP response code : 302
```

The following are the Parameters I'm using with the cfexchange tag :

- Exchange Server IP
- Exchange User
- Exchange Password
- Inbox Name

Note: I have installed the SSL certificate using keytool.

Answer (score 2):

the response code is a 302, which is a redirect. To see exactly what is going on, I'd try this:

1. Install [Fiddler](http://fiddler2.com)
2. [Configure Fiddler to intercept HTTPS connections](http://fiddler2.com/fiddler/help/httpsdecryption.asp) . You'll probably have to import Fiddler's certificate, but that's covered in the linked page.
3. Set the ProxyHost and ProxyPort attributes in  (or whichever tag you're using to connect
4. re-run the code and watch the request/response to see what the content of the problematic response is and where it's redirecting you to. This may be enough to diagnose the problem

Comment: Thanks Barnyr. Will try Fiddler and see if I can get any clue.

Answer (score 0):

Sure you don't mean `<cfexchangeconnection>` which is described at http://livedocs.adobe.com/coldfusion/8/htmldocs/help.html?content=Tags_d-e_13.html?

Comment: This is the code which I'm using to connect:
<cfexchangeConnection

     action="open"
     username="#username#"
     password="#password#" 
     server="#exchangeserverip#"
     connection="#connectionname#"
  mailboxname="#mailboxname#"
  protocol="#protocol#">

Answer (score 0):

I'd also try running Charles on this to see exactly what's being sent and what's coming back and from where. Is the 302 coming back from the exchange server? Or some kind of firewall in between?